# Is there a way to let a class know that something subscribed to its delegate successfully ran?

Tags: c#, delegates

I have one class called TerminalCommandScanUtility.cs with a delegate called ScanUtility:

```
public static event Action scanUtilityEvent;
public void ScanUtility()
{
    if (scanUtilityEvent != null)
    {
        scanUtilityEvent();
    }
}
```

In another class called FolderEvent.cs, I listen for this delegate being fired as follows:

```
bool isScannable;
TerminalCommandScanUtility.scanUtilityEvent += StartFolderScan;

void StartFolderScan()
{
    if(!isScannable)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        //How can I inform TerminalCommandScanUtility that this folder was scannable, and thus ran?
    }
}
```

When the scan utility runs, I want it to be able to know that a folder's isScannable variable was true so that I can display some feedback text for the user like "Despite running the function.. nothing was scanned", or "One folder has begun scanning!"

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for `TerminalCommandScanUtility` and a corresponding event handler. There is a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924612/detect-variable-change-c-sharp).